# UICollectionView crash when deleting last item

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to update the uicollection view whenever I delete a item. All the cells are deleting fine but if I delete the last cell in that collection view App crashes and I have put

```
[self.collectionview performBatchUpdates:^{
        [postarray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        [self.collectionview deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:1]]];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

The error I got is  'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 17 beyond bounds [0 .. 16]'  . Even array and collection view item starts at same index,I got this message

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message with the same lines of code, and it turned out it had nothing to do with the UICollectionView data source, but with a parallel array in another part of the app that updated its contents after but not its active index after the delete.

To find errors like this, enable Exception breakpoints: [NSRangeException when deleting last UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234269/nsrangeexception-when-deleting-last-uicollectionviewcell/36234700?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 0):

Just inverse your two lines. You need to remove cell before to remove your object.

```
[self.collectionview performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self.collectionview deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:1]]];
        [postarray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

Comment: Thanks.but still crash occurs after inverse two lines

Comment: Is it the same error message ?
Replace :
[postarray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
By :
[postarray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];