# NSRangeException when deleting last UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with 1 section. The user can delete cells from the collection, and I use this code for removal:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
   [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]]];
   [self.media removeObjectAtIndex:i];
} completion:nil];
```

This works fine for every cell except for the last cell in the collection, which crashes the app every time with the error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]`

NSZombies aren't showing me a stack trace so I put a breakpoint on every line in my code that accesses an array but none were hit, and I found that this error is thrown after `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths`, `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` and `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`, but before `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

What could be causing this crash? How can I debug it?

There are some similar SO posts, but this one from 2 years ago has no answer [UICollectionView crash when deleting last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041651/uicollectionview-crash-when-deleting-last-item), and this one only solves the problem if you want to delete the whole section: [Removing the last Cell in UICollectionView makes a Crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447065/removing-the-last-cell-in-uicollectionview-makes-a-crash-ios)

UPDATE, here are the data source delegate methods that run before the crash:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(floorf(screenWidth/3), 200);
}
```

Comment: whatever cell index the user clicked on. It doesn't crash on those lines

Comment: Try using [self.media removeObjectAtIndex:i] before using the batch update block

Comment: try to reload collection view after deleting cell and removing object from array.

Comment: I've tried every possible order of `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths`, `removeObjectAtIndex`, with and without the `performBatchUpdates` blcok and all of them crash the same way

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your implementation of collection view data source and delegate methods.

Comment: added the ones that run before the crash, the other delegate methods are never reached

Comment: Hey, come to the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the Exceptions Breakpoint and you'll find where exactly it is crashing.

[image]

Comment: I've edited my answer to include what can help to track the bug. :)